# Hide blinking text cursor on iOS devices

Tags: javascript, ios, css

I am looking to hide the blinking text cursor. Is there a webkit? I am looking to do this via CSS or JS. I want to target a class or ID

Answer (score 0):

Apply a text color of transparent and a text-shadow color.

```css
input {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

input.masked {
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text"  />

<input class="masked" type="text" />
```